# java reading text file and assigning whole line to a string

Tags: java, file

I did try to search for any possible questions regarding this, but none seem to work exactly for me

here is some code I have to read all files in a subdirectory, the method takes the name of the file to look for and its directory

```
 public static Account FileRead(String fname, String dir) throws blankException {
    File file = new File(dir + fname);
    try {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

            String type = sc.nextLine();

            if (type.equals("S") || type.equals("C")) {
                String pin = sc.nextLine();
                double balance = sc.nextDouble();
                String name = sc.next();
                String address = sc.next();
                String date = sc.next();

                if (type.equals("S")) {

                    return new SavingAccount(pin, balance, name, address, date);
                }
                if (type.equals("C")) {

                    return new CheckingAccount(pin, balance, name, address, date);
                }
                throw new blankException("no account type given");
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}//end file reader
```

my problem is that for address, the scanner only takes the frist "word", as in if address in the file is "1234 house drive", address is only 1234.how can I have it where address is "1234 house drive"

also, all the files are in this format

```
type
pin
balance
name
address
date
```

Comment: Just use `Scanner#nextLine()` and read each line of input separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take it using `.nextLine()`. It will take everything that you entered.

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work, could there be a reason why?

Comment: ah never mind, I seem to have gotten it to work

Comment: So, its completely working?

Comment: yes it is working completely

Comment: Can you try to accept my answer? I wonder if it works when question marked as duplicate :D

Comment: ah yes I should probably do that

Comment: it worked, thanks!